# view.invalidate not working

Tags: android

I have a `PuzzleView` class which extends View and refers it in xml in main class. It is shown in emulator without any error. But the invalidate function in PuzzleView is not working. That is the main class xml that contains view doesn't refresh. But it will be worked when directly using setContentView(PuzzleView) in main class. I know what is wrong when using xml. Please help me.

I also used

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.layout.game);
vg.invalidate();
```

in PuzzleView class. But it throws null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

your findViewById() is wrong

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.game);
vg.invalidate();
```

Hope this will work.use R.id.game.not R.layout.game

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But  i tried it. it also throws null pointer exception

Comment: No. I want to refresh the view class that is inside xml.

Answer (score 0):

If this doesn't work

```
vg.invalidate(); // Use this only if you are calling this from UI thread
```

Try Using [postInvalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate%28%29)

```
vg.postInvalidate(); // Use this if you are calling this from non-UI thread
```

**Note** : Read Comments along with code line